# Getting error creating MailMessage with docx body VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create an Outlook mail using word document as a body in VB.

Right now, I have such code:

```
    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim oMail As Object

    wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    doc = wd.documents.Open("C:\Users\Andrey\source\repos\rpa_sendMessage\Message.docx")
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    wd = Nothing

    oMail = Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
    With oMail
        .BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText
        editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        .Display()
    End With
```

Visual Studio 2019, sending an error on the "Application.CreateItem" part;

Error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

I would be very grateful if you could help or give me some advice on my problem!
THANKS!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem in VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645131/using-outlook-application-activeinspector-currentitem-in-vsto)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you need to call that `CreateItem` method on an `Outlook.Application` object. According to the error message, you are calling it on the type, rather than an instance of the type.